# Use two yup schemas for the same react form component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, yup

I have a form for creating a product in react using yup and react hook form. That same form could be used for updating the product so I thought that maybe I could reuse that react functional component I declared for creating and updating.
I defined the following interfaces and yup schemas to handle validation and declare what values I'll be working with when the validation is successful:

```
export interface CreateProductFormValues{
    name: string
    description: string
    typeOfProduct: ProductType | ''
    stock: number
    price: number
    discount?: number | undefined
    file: File
}

export const CreateProductSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    description: yup.string().required(),
    typeOfProduct: yup.mixed<ProductType | ''>().oneOf(['Medicine', 'Other']).required(),
    stock: yup.number().nullable().typeError('Stock must have a number').integer('Stock must be an integer number').required('Stock is required').positive('Stock must be a positive number'),
    price: yup.number().nullable().required().moreThan(0),
    discount: yup.number().positive().lessThan(100),
    file: yup.mixed<File>().required('An image is necessary').test('fileSize', 'The file is too large', (value) => {
        if(value instanceof File){
            return value && value.size <= 15*1024*1024;
        }
    })
    .test('fileType', 'Unsupported File Format', (value) => {
        return value && ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'].includes(value.type);
    })
});

export interface UpdateProductFormValues{
    name: string
    description: string
    typeOfProduct: ProductType | ''
    stock: number
    price: number
    discount?: number | undefined
    file?: File | undefined
}

export const UpdateProductSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    description: yup.string().required(),
    typeOfProduct: yup.mixed<ProductType | ''>().oneOf(['Medicine', 'Other']).required(),
    stock: yup.number().nullable().typeError('Stock must have a number').integer('Stock must be an integer number').required('Stock is required').positive('Stock must be a positive number'),
    price: yup.number().nullable().required().moreThan(0),
    discount: yup.number().positive().lessThan(100),
    file: yup.mixed<File>().test('fileSize', 'The file is too large', (value) => {
        if(value instanceof File){
            return value && value.size <= 15*1024*1024;
        }else if(value === undefined || value === null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
    .test('fileType', 'Unsupported File Format', (value) => {
        if(value instanceof File){
            return value && ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'].includes(value.type);
        }else if(value === undefined || value === null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

When creating the product a file is always required (an image for the product) but when updating a product it isn't. I tried multiple ways of declaring the form hook but I always get an error with the file field since it is declared in both interfaces and they have different types (`File` & `File | undefined`).

For now I resorted to having two react functional components that repeats the same code for the form, one using the create schema and values and the other using the update ones.

An example of how I'm using the form values and schema:

```
interface ProductFormProps {
    isLoading: boolean
    isOpen: boolean
    setIsOpen: (x: boolean) => void
    onSubmit: (x: CreateProductFormValues) => Promise<void>
}

export const CreateProductDialog: React.FC<ProductFormProps> = ({ isLoading, isOpen, setIsOpen, onSubmit }) => {
    const { handleSubmit, reset, control, watch, formState, formState: { errors } } = useForm<CreateProductFormValues>({
        resolver: yupResolver(CreateProductSchema)
    });...
```